# What is this Error In ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse) at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url) at staticpages.btnsubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Vinod\wwwroot\staticpages.master.cs:line 97

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? For example the content of the btnsubmit_Click function?

Answer (score 4):

It probably means you're using Response.Redirect inside of a try/catch block. We can't tell for certain, since you did not supply us with the code.

Comment: Ok Sir I will Provide U Further Details Of btnsubmit_Click function

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace of the exception clearly indicates that a Response.Redirect is taking place.  A simple try catch around that line of code should do the trick.

```
try
{
  Response.Redirect(somewhere);
}
catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Response.Redirect calls Thread.Abort internally](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/312629) to abort the current request. There's a [few workarounds available](http://www.c6software.com/articles/ThreadAbortException.aspx) if it bugs you.